# Repeat the value from left table if date from right table falls between start date and end date

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I would like to join my two tables on [Group] and [YearMonth] Dates. Where [YRMO_NB] from Table 2 falls between [ENR_START] AND [ENR_END] from Table 1 then repeat the value of column [PHASE] for each related row, just like the second picture last column = [PHASE] and leaves unmatched rows blank.

I did this which only gives me exact matches:

```
ON A.GROUP = PHASE.GROUP
AND A.YRMO_NB = PHASE.ENR_START
```

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

```
ON A.GROUP = PHASE.GROUP 
AND A.YRMO_NB >= PHASE.ENR_START
and A.YRMO_NB <= PHASE.ENR_END
```